# NHibernate QueryOver get time from datetime property

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, queryover

I'm saving both the date and the time as `DateTime` in my SQL Server database, and I have a `DateTime` property in my mappings. In my query I need to access the date individually and the time as well. With date I have no problem but when trying to get the time from DateTime I get following error:

> Additional information: could not resolve property: TimeOfDay of: IWS.DataContracts.ServicesPlanning

Saving the time in a other property is not what I want even though I tried it and can't get it working either.

Query with `QueryOver`:

```
Session.QueryOver<ServicesPlanning>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.TeamMember, () => stm)
    .Where(() => stm.Id == _memberId)
    .Where(x => (x.AllDay && (x.StartDate == _startDate && x.EndDate == _endDate)) ||
        (!x.AllDay && x.StartDate.Date == _startDate && x.EndDate.Date == _endDate 
                && (x.StartDate.TimeOfDay > _endTime.Value || x.EndDate.TimeOfDay < _startTime.Value)))
    .RowCount() > 0;
```

Query with LINQ:

```
return Session
        .Query<ServicesPlanning>()
        .Where(x => x.TeamMember.Id == _memberId)
        .Any(x => (x.AllDay && (x.StartDate.Date == _startDate && x.EndDate.Date == _endDate)) ||
        (!x.AllDay && x.StartDate.Date == _startDate && x.EndDate.Date == _endDate && (x.StartDate.TimeOfDay > _endTime.Value || x.EndDate.TimeOfDay < _startTime.Value)));
```

Purpose of query: check if there already is a planning with this date or time so we don't have overlaps.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried LINQ instead of QueryOver?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt Yes but I seem to get the same error. I will post my LINQ query above aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manipulate what's in the database for comparison, why don't you adjust the parameter?

If your database contains for example `2016-01-01T08:00:00` as date, and you want to query records with a date on `2016-01-01` regardless of time, you can query date "between" `2016-01-01T00:00:00` and `2016-01-01T23:59:59`, like so:

```
.Where(x => (x.AllDay && (x.StartDate == _startDate && x.EndDate == _endDate)) ||
    (!x.AllDay && x.StartDate >= _startDate.Date && x.StartDate < _startDate.Date.AddDays(1))...
```

Comment: I think this, with NH is the only current option.  NH would need to be told how to translate DateTime.TimeOfDay property to it's SQL equivalent, if there was one.

Comment: But the problem is I need to check on time. Its a simple calendar so my validations are that I cannot have 2 events on the same time.